# rails 4 has_many :through default order

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a project model that has many tasks, through a join model. The order of the tasks are stored on the project_tasks model.

How do I do the equivalent of the below in rails 4?

```
has_many :project_tasks
has_many :tasks, :through => :project_tasks, :order => 'project_tasks.position'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
has_many :project_tasks, -> { order(:position) }
has_many :tasks, through: :project_tasks
```

I hope this helps now in rails 4 and 5 you have scopes for that sort of thing. PS: Keep in mind now when you call `project_tasks` it will call this scope if you dont want that make scope on model `project_tasks`.